# Iteracion dentro de un map

Tags: javascript

Quiero iterar sobre cada palabra, con un for o map pero no se como hacerlo

quiero iterar los caracteres de las cadenas en el for que esta adentro del map

```
array=["hola","mundo"];
     array.map(value=>
            for(let i=0; i<value.length; i++){

        }
            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realmente la función map ya itera a través de tus elementos. No necesitas añadir ninguna iteración adicional con ningún bucle.

Esta función recorrerá cada uno de los elementos de tu array y te devolverá un nuevo array con el resultado. Como en tu caso no necesitas devolver si no que solamente necesitas mostrar los resultados mediante un `console.log`, podrás mostrarlo directamente dentro de la función.

Para recorrer los caracteres de cada palabra puedes usar la función `split` para dividir las cadenas de texto en un array con sus caracteres y después un bucle `foreach` para recorrerlos y mostrarlos.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```js
var array=["hola","mundo"];

var arrayObtenido = array.map(function(elemento){ 
   console.log("Texto: " + elemento);
   var caracteres = elemento.split("");
   caracteres.forEach(function(caracter) {
      console.log(caracter);
   }); 
});
```

Comment: quiero iterar por los caracteres de las palabras

Comment: @hubman ¿Quieres que te devuelva un array con los carácteres de ambas palabras? ¿O que es lo que buscas exactamente?

Comment: solo iterarlos, mostrarlos con console

Comment: @hubman ¿Tienes que utilizar obligatoriamente un .map? ¿O te valdría con un bucle?

Comment: quisiera un map si es posible

Comment: @hubman Ya he editado mi respuesta. Te sugiero que edites también tu pregunta dejando claro que necesitas utilizar la función map y que necesitas obtener los caracteres correspondientes de cada palabra. Así podrás ayudar a futuros lectores.

Answer (score 2):

Saludos con el método map, puedes hacer el recorrido del siguiente modo:

```
palabras = ["hola", "mundo"]

var dictado = palabras.map((palabra) => {
  console.log(palabra)
})
```

Como puedes observar declaro la variable dictado para contener el bucle que se hará, dentro del método map con una arrow function paso como argumento a **palabra** pues será la variable que ahora tenga reconocido cada atributo del arreglo que declaré arriba.

Un modo mas de hacer iteraciones sin un for o foreach por ejemplo al menos no de modo explícito

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Podría utilizar el forEach de esta manera:

```js
let array=["hola","mundo"];
array.forEach(element=>{
    console.log(element);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Con un for podria ser asi

```js
    let miArray = ["hola","mundo"];
    
    for ( let i = 0; i < miArray.length; i++ ) {
        console.log(miArray[i]);
    }
```